# Beginner questions about SQL and relational algebra

Tags: relational-theory

I'm doing some exercices waiting for the exam. I have some doubt.

**RELATIONAL ALGEBRA**

- > These are the table:
  >
  > > Newspaper (**Cod_n**, Name_n, Publisher)
  > >
  > > Article (**Cod_a**, Title, Topic, Cod_N)
  >
  > *Request* : Find out the name of the newspapers that have published a topic deal with motorcycle at least
  >
  > *My solution*: π_name ( σ_topic = "motorcycle" (newspaper naturaljoin article))
  >
  > *Book's solution*: π_name (newspaper naturaljoin σ_topic = "motorcycle" (article))

Are the solution equivalent? Is the only difference between them the "cost of the operation" ?

- 

> The table is the same of the previous exercice.
>
> *Request*: Find out the name of the newspapers that have never published a topic deal with motorcycle
>
> *My solution*:   π_name_n (newspaper naturaljoin (σ_topic notegual "motorcycle" (article)
>
> *Book's solution*:   π_name_n(newspaper naturaljoin (π_cod_n(newspaper) - π_cod_n (σ_topic = "motorcycle" (Article)
>   
>   Are the solution equivalent?

**SQL**

> These are the table:
>
> > Student(**matriculation_number**, surname, name)
> >
> > Exams(**Student**, **subject**, grades, date)
>
> *Request*: Find out students (showing matriculation number) that have passed two exams after 1/1/2000 at least
>
> *My Solution*:
>
> > select distinct matriculation_number
> >
> > from student join exams on matriculation_number = student
> >
> > where data > '2000-01-01'
> >
> > EXCEPT
> >
> > select distinct matriculation_number
> >
> > from student join exams on matriculation_number = students
> >
> > where data =< '2000-01-01'
>
> *Book's solution*:
>
> > select distinct e1.student
> >
> > from exams e1 join e2 on e1.student = e2.student
> >
> > where e1.subject < > e2.subject
> >
> > and e1.date > '2000-01-01'
> >
> > and e2.date > '2000-01-01'

Is the solutions equivalent?

Thank you in advantage for your time.
I'm sorry I don't know how to insert relational algebra's symbol.

Comment: Isn't this 3 questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql query is wrong:

```
- Assume there is a student s1 who has passed one exam 
  after '2000-01-01' and none before. 
  Your query results in {s1} - {} = {s1}. This will be a false positive.

- Assume there is a student s1 that passed three exams 
  after '2000-01-01' and one exam before. 
  Your query results in {s1} - {s1} = {}. This will be a false negative.
```

I'm having a bit of trouble reading your algebra expressions, but the first one looks ok. It should not matter that you do the selection (topic = "motorcycle") after the join instead of joining on the selection.

The second one can't be right. Assume there's a newspaper that published both an article on motorcycle and an article on something else. Your expression will pick the article on something else and therefore return that newspaper (incorrectly).